# IR emitter LED with jack 3.5

Tags: arduino, led, infrared, emitter

Currently I'm using an IR LED connected directly to a PCB where an Arduino UNO is connected. When I send a command with the Arduino, the LED sends what I want to an IR receiver.

[image]

Now I'm thinking to change a bit this solution, because I want to extend the IR emitter, but not with some loose wires, I want to use a jack 3.5 cable.

[image]

Can I just use a mono cable, connecting the two wires to the PCB, and at the other end connect the male plug to a female 3.5 mono plug, where the LED will be soldered? I don't need to have much power because the emitter and the receiver will be very close to each other.

So, my ultimate doubt is if it'll work with a mono cable or do I need a stereo one?

Comment: Hmmm. LED has **two wires** (anode, cathode), mono cable has **two wires** (inner + shield), stereo cable has **three wires** (two inner + shield) so why the doubt about using mono cable?

Comment: Because all I read on the web about this, a lot of DIY, they all use stereo. I don't get why.

Comment: Maybe stereo cables are just more common, or maybe you are confusing a tx with an rx, which usually needs three wires. If you need clarification just add some examples of the DIY tutorials you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a mono cable without any problems. As was mentioned, you only have an anode and cathode which needs to be connected to, so using a stereo one would leave you with an unused terminal.